# Pass PHP variable value into HTML label

Tags: php, html, label

Html Code

```
<ul><li><label class="control-label"><?php echo $name; ?></label></li></ul>
```

Php

```
<?php   
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = "pizza";

    $name = "";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);


    $email = "example@gmail.com";
    $query = "Select customer.CustName from customer inner join login on customer.CustID = login.CustID where login.email = '$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name =  $row["CustName"] ;
    }

    mysql_close($conn);?>
```

I have tried to echo the variable $name into the label, but the variable value didn't appear at the label. Please help me for this problem. The output i want is display the value "Example" into the label.

Error code : Notice: Undefined variable: name

Comment: Did you check for errors first? The variable needs to be defined before you try to use it.

Comment: Read up on how labels work.

Comment: So if i defined the variable first, but it also cant display the value $name. I have defind $name = "" before

Answer (score 4):

`<label>` tags do *not* have a `value` attribute. The label text goes in between an opening and closing `</label>` tag.

```
<label class="control-label"><?php echo $name; ?></label>
```

See the [MDN page for `<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) to learn more about this tag.

Comment: I got the error of  Undefined variable: name

Comment: Then you don't have a variable called `$name` in your code. Make sure your variable is named correctly what this code has access to it.

Comment: I have defined it as Example, why it still cant display?

Comment: I have no idea. I can't see all of your code. But obviously that variable is not available in that piece of code. You need to figure out how to get it there.

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Obviously your query is returning no records. You need to figure out why.

Comment: i have tested in mysql, it return a row. But the error code display is Undefined variable: name

Comment: I don't know what else to twll you. Either your database is returning no rows or that variable is not available where you have that HTML. You need to figure out which one of the two cases is the actual problem.

Comment: I have solve the problem by Put the <?php ?> to the top of the code, then everything goes well, because previously i put <?php ?> in end of the code.